# How to re-use a terraform module in multiple configurations?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a terraform plan that defines most of my BQ environment.
I'm working on a cross-region deployment which will replicate some of my tables to multiple regions.

Rather than copy pasting the same module in every place that I need it at, I'd like to define the module in one place and just call that on every configuration that needs it.

Example I have the following file structure

```
./cross_region_tables
 -> tables.tf
./foo
 -> tables.tf
./bar
 -> tables.tf
```

I'd like to define `some_module` in `./cross_region_tables/tables.tf` like so

```
output "some_module" {
   x = something
   region = var.region
}
```

Then I'd like just call `some_module` from `./foo/tables.tf`

The problem is that I don't know how to call this specific module, since `./cross_region_tables/tables.tf` will contain several table definitions (as output objects). I know how to import a child module, but I don't know how to call a specific output within that child module

Comment: You could use `for_each` to get all the outputs where the key could probably be the region. Then you could reference the desired output with `module.<name>.some_module["<region key>"]`. But I think more details are needed to be sure.

Comment: `for_each` is not an option for me, since terraform identifies my modules by name and some of these modules already exist, so for each turns `foo` into `foo["some_region"]` and tf identifies it as a new module, then it attempts to destroy the original `foo` module which in turn fails because it would be deleting one of my existent tables too

Comment: So there is already some code for those modules, i.e., something got created?

Comment: Yes we were currently working on single region, and we had modules for our tables. Now we're going cross region and we'd like to avoid rewriting the whole modules just to change the region

Comment: You could use aliased provider configuration for that as well, but I still feel it's hard to tell based on the information provided. https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly

Comment: What do you mean by: `call a specific output within that child module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by adding a module object to the child module with a variable for the region, then calling the child from each regional configuration and passing the region as a variable.

in child folder `main.tf`:

```
variable "region" = {}

module "foo" {
   x = "something"
   y = "something_else"
   region = var.region
}
```

in regional folder for `regionX`

```
variable "region" = {
    default = regionX
}

module "child" {
    source = "../path/to/child"
    region = var.region
}
```

in regional folder for `regionY`

```
variable "region" = {
    default = regionY
}

module "child" {
    source = "../path/to/child"
    region = var.region
}
```

repeat for as many regions as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the provider to your modules and each provider with a different
region...

That is well documented here:
https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly

```
# The default "aws" configuration is used for AWS resources in the root
# module where no explicit provider instance is selected.
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"
}

# An alternate configuration is also defined for a different
# region, using the alias "usw2".
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "usw2"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

# An example child module is instantiated with the alternate configuration,
# so any AWS resources it defines will use the us-west-2 region.
module "example" {
  source    = "./example"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.usw2
  }
}
```

---

The other part is what you mentioned:

> The problem is that I don't know how to call this specific module, since `./cross_region_tables/tables.tf` will contain several table definitions

Resources within that module (`cross_region_tables`) can be turned off/on with variables

Comment: Yes but this assumes a structure where every regional configuration is handled in 1 file. We have different configurations for each region in separate files

Comment: @Dasph You can have multiple files that is not a problem, actually that is how must people have it